# How could I get a pdf file generated in a web project, and print it in another project in the same solution c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution that contains several projects, and in one of this projects I return a PDF file that contains data to print.
In another project still in the same solution that handles the print part and I want to take the returned pdf files and print them in this project

How will I do ?

Comment: Why can you not call the printer method from your different project passing the file as parameter? 
You need to add your printer project as a reference to your Project that returns the pdf file ? 
Without more code it is quite difficult to understand what you exactly mean.

Comment: Why not adding a class library project with the PDF generating logic and referencing it in both projects?

Comment: @DimitriBosteels   I have a project class library that can manage the printer, I will work on an Evolis Zenius RFID printer. I have a web project Asp.MVC that can generate PDF files. So I want to recover the PDF file and try to print it from the class library project, by doing a unit test. For now I have a test method that allows to print data in xml. I now want to do the same for printing PDF files

Comment: for a unit test, test the method with a client to get your pdf file, then use the result from your testClient to call you printing method

Answer (score 0):

In the project where you handle the printing, add a reference to the project where you create the pdf: right click on the project’s “References” > “Add Reference” and then select namespace in the other project where you create the pdf. Now, always in the project where you handle the printing, you can call whatever method your other project has to expose the pdf file you have just created. Something like this:

```
namespace myProject.printer
{
    Public class Print
    {
        public void PrintFile(myOtherProj.PdfCreator.GetPdf file)
        { 
            // code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That forces both project being operative/online at the same time. Making a separate DLL with the pdf creation logic makes more sense IMHO.

Comment: @bradbury9 isn’t that an assumption, considering they’re both in the same solution?

Comment: It is not, it would be wiser making them into a single solution indeed, but a compiled assembly can be referenced without need of adding the whole project to both solutions.

Comment: @bradbury9 OP says: “in another project still in the same solution”. They are!

Comment: In the question title it says the project that generates the document is a website, hence the need of a separate new project.

Comment: Oh, web project... I must’ve missed that somehow! Yeah, making a separate project/dll for the creation of the pdf makes much more sense, even though I sense both the printing and creation project are gonna be just in the same root folder...

Comment: Okey I will test your propositions

Answer (score 0):

You should consider making your solution in the following way:

- SharedLogic: Containing document creation logic (could be a DLL or a web service)
- Web project: References the SharedLogic project
- Printing project: References the SharedLogic project. Calls the GetDocument method and prints its content.

Comment: I still don’t get how this is different form my answer

Comment: The project that creates the document is a web project. You suggest a two project solution, I suggest a three project solution.

Comment: OP said there are **several** projects, I’m only saying how to make a working link between the two. Maybe we’re suggesting the same thing

Comment: @DavideVitali  I have a project class library that can manage the printer, I will work on an Evolis Zenius RFID printer.
I have a web project Asp.MVC  that can generate PDF files.
So I want to recover the PDF file and try to print it from the class library project,  by doing a unit test.

For now I have a test method that allows to print data in xml. I now want to do the same for printing PDF files

Comment: @bradbury9    I have a project class library that can manage the printer, I will work on an Evolis Zenius RFID printer.
I have a web project Asp.MVC  that can generate PDF files.
So I want to recover the PDF file and try to print it from the class library project,  by doing a unit test.

For now I have a test method that allows to print data in xml. I now want to do the same for printing PDF files

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is the method test thati use it for xml, and i want do the same for a pdf 
[TestMethod]
    public void EvolisPrinterCanPrintMockup()
    {
        var jobTemplate = new MockupJobTemplate(
            () => XElement.Parse(Resources.Carte_ABO_L1_18_19_SMC),
            "TEST Print XML");

        IPrinter printer = EvolisPrinter.Create(new EvolisPrinterConfiguration
        {
            Name = TestPrinterName,
            Landscape = true

        }, new PcScSharpSmartCardService());

        var job = printer.CreateJob(jobTemplate);
        job.ReadChipUid = true;
        var uid = (string)job.Print();

        Assert.IsNotNull(uid);
    }
```